# how to export the data of table without headers to CSV?

Tags: php, export-to-csv

i want to export content of my table in CSV. 
NB : my result is to have a content without the headers of table.
so i want to attempt  to csv file which contains Mike  Stuntman  Cascadaeur 
Mister  pink  Gangster

this is my script:

```html
<?php 

$lignes   = array();
$lignes[] =  array('header1', 'header2' , 'header3');
$lignes[] =  array('Mike', 'Stuntman', 'Cascadeur');
$lignes[] =  array('Mister', 'Pink', 'Gangster');

array_to_csv_download($lignes,"export.csv");


function array_to_csv_download($array, $file, $delimiter=" ") {
    
    $fichier_csv = fopen($file, 'w+');
 // les problèmes d'affichage des caractères internationaux (les accents par exemple)
 fprintf($fichier_csv, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
 
 foreach($array as $ligne){
  //Formate une ligne en CSV et l'écrit dans le fichier export.csv
    fputcsv($fichier_csv, $ligne, $delimiter);
 }

 // fermeture du fichier csv
 fclose($fichier_csv);

 // how to export a data  table without the header of table ?
 if (!file_exists($file)) { 
    return false;
 }else {
   //set appropriate headers
   //header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
   header('Content-Type: application/csv');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
   header('Expires: 0');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
   header('Pragma: public');
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
   ob_clean();
   flush();

   //read the file from disk and output the content.
   readfile($file);
   exit;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
array_shift($lignes)
```

or

```
unset($lignes[0])
```

before executing

```
array_to_csv_download($lignes,"export.csv");
```

Comment: think u Klin for u response :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_shift` function which will remove first item of array:

```
$lignes   = array();
$lignes[] =  array('header1', 'header2' , 'header3');
$lignes[] =  array('Mike', 'Stuntman', 'Cascadeur');
$lignes[] =  array('Mister', 'Pink', 'Gangster');

array_shift($lignes);
print_r($lignes);
```